# Can't bind to 'startingCategory' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, properties, bind

I am stuck with Angular 6 code telling me "Can't bind to 'startingCategory' since it isn't a known property of 'div'." I am still fairly new to Angular, so please be kind :)

I'm trying to just read properties from my typescript and display them as properties within a div.

/document.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-document',
    templateUrl: './document.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./document.component.css']
})
export class DocumentComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string = "Documents";
    startingCategory: number = 0;
    orgId: number = 0;
    isAdmin: boolean = false;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

/document.component.html

```
<div id="DocumentManager" 
    data-title="{{title}}" 
    data-startingCategory="{{startingCategory}}" 
    data-orgId="{{orgId}}" 
    data-isAdmin="{{isAdmin}}">
</div>
```

Comment: How are you binding in html can you please show ?

Comment: Just updated it, first post on stack overflow. Still getting used to the interface. :)

Comment: Let me know if below helps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the attr binding way:

```
<div id="DocumentManager"
    [attr.data-title]="title"
    [attr.data-startingCategory]="startingCategory"
    [attr.data-orgId]="orgId"
    [attr.data-isAdmin]="isAdmin" > 
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be working. I'll have to test once I get my other library sorted out, but I definitely appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div id="DocumentManager"> 
    data-title={{title}}
    data-startingCategory={{startingCategory}}
    data-orgId={{orgId}} 
    data-isAdmin={{isAdmin}}
</div>
```

In place of

```
<div id="DocumentManager"
    data-title="{{title}}" 
    data-startingCategory="{{startingCategory}}" 
    data-orgId="{{orgId}}" 
    data-isAdmin="{{isAdmin}}"
</div>
```

Angular is complaining correctly as these are not properties of div if you check the html documentation. "button" has click property similarly onChange is one such property

Comment: I see what you mean. What would be the best way to have those items as properties? We have another library that reads those properties (even though they aren't technically div properties) and uses them as if they are parameters for a web service call.

Comment: That library will have different tags then I do not see why will you do in div